# Trapping shell script doesn't work when used over SSH

Tags: shell-script, ssh, scripting, signals, trap

I am working on `client` and want to run a script on `server` which includes a `trap`.

The following minimal example works fine if I connect to `server` and run it in an interactive SSH session:

```
user@client:~$ ssh user@server
user@server:~$ sh -c 'trap "echo exiting..." EXIT'
exiting...
user@server:~$
```

However, if I don't connect to `server` interactively, but add the command to the `ssh` command, it doesn't work anymore:

```
user@client:~$ ssh user@server -- sh -c 'trap "echo exiting..." EXIT'
user@client:~$
```

Comment: `ssh` builds the remote command by concatenating its arguments (separating with spaces), kinda like what `echo` would print from the same arguments. In your case the remote command is `sh -c trap "echo exiting..." EXIT`, basically equivalent to `sh -c trap`. It's a matter of local quoting. Can you take it from here? You may find this question helpful: [How can I single-quote or escape the whole command line in Bash conveniently?](https://superuser.com/q/1531395/432690)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try something like this:

On the client machine, save the command in a file named (e.g.) .stackexchange:

```
user@client:~$ echo 'trap "echo exiting…" EXIT' > .stackexchange
```

Then, run a regular SSH command to connect to the server:

```
user@client:~$ ssh user@server
```

Once connected, run the command from the file:

```
user@server:~$ sh .stackexchange
exiting…
user@server:~$
```